# Make tkinter display the output in the window created, not in my bash terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

I am tinkering with tkinter for the first time. I got this from geeksforgeeks.org (changed it a little)

When I run:

> pedro@pedro-512ssd:~/myPython/tkinter$ ./newWindow_display_textv5.py

in bash, I see my window, but the output "key was pressed" appears in bash and not in my shiny new window.

Is it possible to make the output appear in my new window?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# Import all files from 
# tkinter and overwrite 
# all the tkinter files 
# by tkinter.ttk
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def myWindow2():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("A New Window")
    window.config(bg='light blue')
    window.geometry('640x480')
    
    # function to be called when 
    # keyboard buttons are pressed 
    def key_press(event): 
        key = event.char 
        print(key, 'was pressed') 
      
          
    # here we are binding keyboard 
    # with the main window 
    window.bind('<Key>', lambda a : key_press(a)) 
      
    mainloop()
    
myWindow2()
```

Comment: So where do you want it showed in your new `Tk` window?You may need to use a widget like `Text` or `Entry`.

Comment: use a text widget instead of print statement

Answer (score 3):

You could always do this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas

def func(event):
      c.create_text(0, 0, text="Pressed key {}".format(event.char)) #0, 0 are coordinates (0, 0 is top left)

window = Tk()
window.title("some tkinter window")
window.geometry("640x480")
c = Canvas(window, width=640, height=480)
c.pack()
window.bind("<Key>", func)
window.mainloop()
```

This works just fine for me.

Edit:

Do this

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
text = c.create_text(0, 0, text="", anchor="nw")
def func(event):
       c.itemconfig(text, text="Pressed key {}".format(event.char))

window = Tk()
window.title("some tkinter window")
window.geometry("640x480")
c = Canvas(window, width=640, height=480)
c.pack()
window.bind("<Key>", func)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Addition to the answer: instead of printing the output, you are placing it in the canvas with `create_text`.

Comment: Thanks, however, this does not show up very clearly. It is right at the top left, as if half the text is out of the window, so I can't read it. I tried changing 0, 0 for 2, 2 but that did not help. Also, it seems that, when I press another key, the output is written over the previous output. Can you tweak it to display more clearly? Thanks again!

Comment: you could add the option `anchor="nw"`  to the `create_text` to make it display better

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a label on your window.
for example `someLabel = Label( window, text='set Text here' )`
there are other commands for the positioning of said label